# How can i clear the data in table widget with index using pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

Here is my program i want to clear the data,i saw remove row method but its is removing the index row.How can i clear the data without assigning new item in table widget.

Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self. table = QtGui.QTableWidget(3, 6, self)
        self.table.setGeometry(10, 70, 500,300)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        fnt = self.table.font()
        fnt.setPointSize(11)
        self.table.setFont(fnt)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("S.no, Item Description,Qty,Rate(Rs:),Subtotal,"",").split(','))

        all_data = [("1", "Acne-aid Wash Facial Cleansing", 191.72, 0),
                    ("2", "AMoisturizer", 90, 0),
                    ("3", "Brightening eye cream", 40, 0)]

        for r, row_data in enumerate(all_data):
            for c, value in zip((0, 1, 3, 4), row_data):
                it = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.table.setItem(r, c, it)

            btn = QtGui.QPushButton(icon=QtGui.QIcon("trash1.png"))
            btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.cleardata,r))
            self.table.setCellWidget(r, 5, btn)
        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 600, 300)
        self.show()

    def cleardata(self,r):
        print r
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have to write for example an update method, incl connected pushbutton to do that.

Comment: can you give any example sir to update the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to iterate over the row, get the QTableWidgetItem and set an empty text:

```py
def cleardata(self, r):
    for c in range(self.table.columnCount()):
        it = self.table.item(r, c)
        if it is not None:
            it.setText("")
        w = self.table.cellWidget(r, c)
        if isinstance(w, QtGui.QLabel):
            w.clear()
```

Comment: if you don't mine can i ask one doubt

Comment: how can i clear data of  self.table.cellWidget(s, 4)

Comment: @navyasri Do you want to delete the widget (button) or what do you mean by "clear data"?

Comment: self.item_rate = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.item_rate.setFont(self.fonttable)
        self.table.setCellWidget(ct-1, 3,self.item_rate)

Comment: here in label i set the text default after clicking the button i want to clear the data in that cell widget not widget

Comment: self.item_rate is label using settext i assign a value but now i need to clear that value in cell widget using the index of the row

Comment: eyllanesc sir if you are free can you please check my post